# UIBarButtonItem text two colours

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

i'm trying to find solution to change my UIBarButTonItem text in two colours , i find some functions for UILabel, i change it by my task:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func setColorForText(textForAttribute: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textForAttribute, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }
}
extension UILabel{
    func setTwoColors(firstWord: String, secondWord: String , firstColor:UIColor = .white , secondColor: UIColor = .blue) {
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstWord+secondWord)
        attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: firstWord, withColor: firstColor)
        attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: secondWord, withColor: secondColor)
        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

But I can't really find solution to change **UIBarButtonItem** to looks like this :
[Here is image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbdEp.png)

Comment: `range(of:)` returns the first occurence found, so in your case you have `Label Label`, so you'll color twice the same one.

Comment: (Label Label) is the example , i mean one UIBarButtonItem text with two colours, like first part red , another one blue
@Larme

Comment: There is no visible NSAttributedText property on `UIBarButtonItem`. But you could initiate the button with a CustomView which could be a UILabel, a UIButton with that `.attributedText` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your button and attributes under your controller class like this:

```
let myButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Label 1", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)]) // first word
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " - ", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)])) // intermediate
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Label 2", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)])) // second word
    b.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    
    return b
}()
```

To change color of single word, simply change relative foregroundColor

After that in viewDidLoad call your navBar custom button like that:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
```

and this is the result

[image]